# React app not render after transpiling

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, babeljs

I´m trying to render my react app with redux but it doesn´t work. The console in chrome, firefox and IE don´t throw any error, it´s clean.

I´m gonna to show my config files:

- Webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');

module.exports = {
    // the entry file for the bundle
    entry: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src/app.jsx'),

    // the bundle file we will get in the result
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/client/build'),
        filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    },

    devtool: '#eval-source-map',

    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
    },

    resolve: {
        // Alias. Avoids relative paths.
        alias: {
            common: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src/resources/common'),
            properties: path.resolve(__dirname,
                'client/src/resources/static/properties'),
            react_folder: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src/react_folder'),
            redux_folder: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src/redux_folder'),
            resources: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src/resources'),
            services: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/src/resources/services'),
            utils: path.resolve(__dirname,
                'client/src/resources/common/utils/index'),
        },

        extensions: [
            '.js', '.jsx', '.json',
        ],
    },
```

- My app.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
import {browserHistory, Router} from 'react-router';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux';
import {getMessages} from 'common/i18n';
import {I18n} from 'react-polyglot';
import initialState from 'redux_folder/reducers/initialState/index';
import configureStore from 'redux_folder/store/configureStore';
import routes from 'react_folder/router/routes';

const store = configureStore(initialState);

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);

// Detectar el lenguaje del navegador. Si no lo reconoce español.
const locale = store.getState().session.locale;
const mensajes = getMessages(locale);

// remove tap delay, essential for MaterialUI to work properly
injectTapEventPlugin();

ReactDom.render((
        <Provider store={store}>
            <I18n locale={locale} messages={mensajes}>
                <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
            </I18n>
        </Provider>

), document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

- And finally, my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>XXXXXX</title>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/img/xxxxxx_favico.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/react-select/dist/react-select.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="https://npmcdn.com/react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css">
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/82270d5016.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/switch.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
    <script src="./js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

What can be happen? it´s works when I load my webapp project in express. Now I´m uploading the build folder in a tomcat Server but I think that it is not a problem.

**EDIT**:
All files are loading properly :(
[Network tab firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYwwH.png)

**EDIT2**
In Chrome the source tab: [Source Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koMHB.png)
I can check in this tab that it´s really slow when I open a folder to see the content folder. is it 14MG a huge file? I think that it´s already minified
Thanks!!!

**EDIT3**
Now the bundle is 1,8 MG :) but the problem is the same :(. I removed source-map form webpack.config.js

**EDIT4**
Now I think that the real problem is react-router component. In production the children are null. Any idea?

Comment: do you see that the files (`bundle.js` etc..) are being downloaded properly?

Comment: Hi @Sag1v, How can see that? I can see the file os over 14 Mb and it´s a minimize js. The folder build -index.html

Comment: on the network tab of the developer tools in the browser

Comment: Does your application depend on API calls to get the data to initialise your application? I agree with @Sag1v check your network tab to see what's going on. Check if the JS file is being loaded, and check if any requests are failing with a 404/500 etc.

Comment: I have edited my post with a network tab png. All it`s ok. :(. Thanks -
 @Sag1v and @BugHunterUK

Comment: I have a lot of api rest calls but it´s not neccesary for initialization. @BugHunterUK. The webbApp start with a login form without any api rest call :)